# Dynamic single page Drupal site

Tags: jquery, drupal, history.js, singlepage

I'm looking for some suggestions on how I could implement the following. I'm not at all married to any one solution (module(s)) at this point. That said, I will almost surely be using `Views / Chaos Tools` and `StateHandler / History.js`. I'm open to using `Panels` or `Blocks`, and in fact I would really like to use Panels. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I need to make a site that is just one page and loads node content dynamically (using `AJAX`) into the page above views. The content must be accessible from the node `URLs (node/1)` as well, loading the full site page with the node content "front-and-center" in the viewport.

Please let me know if I can clarify, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work: http://drupal.org/project/views_load_more

I have never used this module, so I know nothing, but I found it recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this actually just works as a Views pager, which doesn't help me in my case.

Comment: Combined with the jQuery waypoints module it should work like you want. Try infinite scrolling here:  http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#examples

Comment: That is very cool.  I just checked that out, and while invite scrolling is very cool (I've used Views Infinite Scroll in the past), it's not what I need in this case.  I need to be able to click on a link and have the content of the referenced node load above the view that linked to it on the same page.  Working with history.js, the resulting link should be directly accessible, too.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about: Thanks for your answer; I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

jquery.ajaxit might do what you want.

It is not the cleanest thinkable solution since it loads the entire page and then only uses the part that you are interested to load into the page via Ajax but it is easy to use and you could combine it with some custom theming to reduce the overhead.

There is a [Drupal 6 module](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxit) ready to use and I have [started a Drupal 7 port](http://drupal.org/node/1226014).

Since the jQuery plugins directory was broken when checked I have created a copy at https://github.com/sDaniel/ajaxit

Here is a sample of the plugin in use: http://www.lamp83.de

Comment: Thanks s.Daniel; this is something similar to what I would like to do, although my implementation would really require some Views integration or some sort of Panel/block awareness.

Comment: OK but check the demo site. The product area uses views. Basically the script doesn't care how the content is produced as long as it's html and can be addressed via any selector.

Comment: I see what you mean, and that would be great except for the fact that I need to be able to load the content above whatever element the link is being clicked from.  I doubt there's a module for that, but perhaps a solution...  Is your Drupal 7 port decently stable?

Comment: It works for me and does it's job but there are some bugs like the module creates a top level menu entry that I need to fix when I have time. 
I think you should be able to do what you want with ajaxit and a little custom scripting. All you would need to do is to change `$.ajaxIt.ajaxItArea = "#to_your_target_selector";` in relation to the link clicked (e.g. `$.ajaxIt.ajaxItArea = "#node-1-content";`in a view where you have the same id on the node) or depending on what exactly you want to do add the id to the element you want to fill. I haven't tested this though.